# WP-CLI can not find Url

Tags: wp-cli

When try use this command:

```
php wp-cli.phar core install --url="http://example.com"
```

the command fails. WordPress was installed, but *WP CLI* complains about an invalid `siteurl` and `home` because I have installed WordPress inside `http://example.com/project-root`.

But if I try use by alias `wp` (`wp core install --url="http://example.com"`) all is ok and url is valid.

What's wrong with the previous command?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Read [the documentation](https://wp-cli.org/config/#global-parameters).

**Long answer:** *WP CLI* needs to know your WordPress root directory. That is not platform, but software specific. This is also needed in *Multisite and Network installs* to determine the current site.

The easiest way to solve this is to use a [YAML configuration file](https://wp-cli.org/config/#config-files) for *WP CLI*. Best is to place this in your users home directory so *WP CLI* searches from the root and upwards for it and uses the options provided there.